# How do I create a share-able header with css content image that is vertically aligned?

Tags: css

I'm trying to implement something similar to GitHub's shareable headers (hover over a header in the [README at the bottom of a repo](https://github.com/maptime/maptime.github.io#readme) and a link icon appears).  I'm using pseudo selectors and a generated content image.

The problem is vertical alignment.  The anchor tag is 29px tall while the heading is 25px.  I tried to make the line height of the anchor tag 25px but the alignment was still off.

[image: share-heading-image]
[Demo on CodePen](http://codepen.io/rhewitt/pen/vELVgz/)

```
<a href="#heading" title="Share me!" class="hover-link">
  <h3 id="heading" class="share-heading">Some awesome heading</h3>
</a>

.share-heading {
  display: inline;
}

a.hover-link {
  content: "";
  line-height: 25px;
}

a.hover-link:hover:after {
  content: url(data:URI.......);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with another pseudo-element and a attribute as the `content`.

```css
.share-heading {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
a.hover-link {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  content: "";
  color: #279ACB;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 25px;
  border:1px dotted grey;
  position: relative;
  height: 25px;

}

a.hover-link:hover::after {
  position: absolute;
  content:attr(title);
  top:110%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  border:1px solid lightblue;
  height: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  width:auto;
  white-space: no-wrap;
  display: block;
  padding:0 1rem;
  background: lightgrey;
  border-radius: .3rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px black;
  
}

a.hover-link:before {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: url(data:image/png;base64,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);

}
```

```html
<a href="{{}}#heading" title="Share me!" class="hover-link">
  <h3 id="heading" class="share-heading">Some awesome heading</h3>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've never seen a case where `vertical-align` was actually the answer.  I would suggest removing all of the extra swag as it gets in the way of seeing what's actually important here.